# Why I can't I install composer on ubuntu using terminal?

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php

I have installed xampp on my (ubuntu 16.04)local machine using installer and I found apache and mysql is working but I am trying to install composer from terminal. It's not working for php as the first command of my code. I think it is not recognizing php as a command. I am trying to write following code on terminal.

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

what I am getting:

```
The program 'php' can be found in the following packages:
* php7.0-cli
 * hhvm
Try: apt install <selected package>
```

**What should I do now?**

I have attached the picture.

Comment: Do as the message suggests, install php-cli. Btw, you do know that Ubuntu 16.04 reached it's end of life over a year ago? Keep using it might put you at risk since it won't get any updates anymore. The same goes for PHP 7.0, which hasn't been supported for over 3 and a half years.

Comment: @M.Eriksson okay

Comment: This question is more sutable for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)